# Codeigniter/PHP How to properly use a for loop?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    <?php 
    print_r($optimum);
    $dataNumRows = count($optimum); 
    ?>

    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $dataNumRows; $i++) : ?>
        <?php echo $cFirstName; ?>
        <?php echo $cLastName; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
```

**My `print_r` inserted in my VIEW shows the following:**

```
Array ( [cFirstName] => Array ( [0] => Tom [1] => Alexa ) [cLastName] => Array ( [0] => Jones [1] => Planter ) )
```

**My MODEL is the following**

```
//Get all the customers currently pending 
//install for the user making the request. 
function getAllCustomersPendingInstall()
{
    $data=array();

    //Need to use sessions to display proper 
    //records for each user. Temp set id to user #7
    $id = 7;

    //query the db and return all record where SalesRepId == $id
    $query = $this->db->get_where('customers', array('SalesRepId' => $id));

        //check logic, if rows exist RETURN all rows, else
        //return message that no pending installs is available.
        if($query->num_rows != 0) {
            foreach($query->result() as $row) {
                $data['cFirstName'][] = $row->customerFirstName;
                $data['cLastName'] [] = $row->customerLastName;
            }
        } else {
            $data = "No pending installs available!";
            return $data;
        }   
//the following var_dump is only showing the last record.
//need to show all rows (which should be 2)
//var_dump($data); exit;
return $data;           
}
```

**My CONTROLLER is the following**

```
{
    $this->load->library('table');
    $this->load->model('GetData');
    $data['optimum'] = $this->GetData->getAllCustomersPendingInstall();
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}
```

And my question is how do I properly use the FOR loop in my VIEW so that I can loop through all the returned rows. As you can see the `print_r` is properly returning the proper rows- However I am unable to loop through them. Thanks for the help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your view:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < $dataNumRows; $i++) : ?>
    <?php echo $optimum['cFirstName'][$i]; ?>
    <?php echo $optimum['cLastName'][$i]; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: This does not echo anything

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is get an associative array for each row returned from the database. Correct me if I'm wrong about that.

Should fix your problem

```
$data = array();
$data_index = 0;
if($query->num_rows != 0) {
            foreach($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[$data_index]['cfirst'] = $row->customerFirstName;
                $data[$data_index]['clast'] = $row->customerLastName;
                $data_index++;
            }
        } else {
            $data = "No pending installs available!";
            return $data;
        }
```

then in your view (where `$customer` is the `$data` array)

```
<?php foreach($customer as $c):?>
<?php echo $c['cfirst'];?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: This worked but what is data_index and why is it necessary to allow the code to function?

Comment: You need to create an array of arrays. The way you were doing it before was creating an associative array with 2 keys, then overwriting the values on each iteration of the foreach loop in your model.

Comment: Thank you for your help and though your answer worked properly I choose the above answer because I felt it blended better with my original code. Thank you!